# QRS Detection in java from ecg byte array

Tags: java

i read ecg byte array from file.now i want to detect QRS of read ecg byte.
how can i acheive this in java.

i get byte array from Lifegain defibrilator(an ecg device).i draw ecg on android from these bytes.now i want to detect QRS complex(term used for calculation of time and voltage of a wave of one heart beat).DATA=LeadData":"-284,-127,-122,17,-35,10,32,10,52,16,49,33,38,69,70,58,45,93,47,88,58,90,149,5,82,-12,-4,40,-34,29,-29,5,-4,-17,-13,-29,-13,-4,-9,-9,-10,-20,-15,-22,-32,-25,-23,-2,-15,-7,-13,-19,-17,-28,-27,-27,-33,-20,-16,-13,-20,-10,-22,-20,-19,-28,-15,-19,-22,-21,-9,-3,-6,-8,-6,-11,-8,-8,-5,-10,-5,-6,-9,-4,-6,3,20,3,14,7,11,10,5,11,5,10,2,10,13,14"

Regards,

shah

Comment: You're aware of the fact that the less effort you put into your question the more like it will be closed, aren't you? Please elaborate and show us what you've got and where your exact problems are.

Comment: I hope you're not doing this in an actual medical context...

Answer (score 2):

If the data you have is the data I think you have, you need to use one of the algorithms to detect your QRS complex.

There are a lot of algorithms out there to detect a QRS complex, one of the easiest is *A Moving Average based Filtering System with its Application to Real-time QRS Detection* by HC Chen and SW Chen (you can get it on http://www.cinc.org/archives/2003/pdf/585.pdf).

The stages are:

- High Pass filtering
- Low Pass filtering
- Descision making stage

From the low pass picture you can notice that now we have the peaks we need to detect our QRS complex. The last stage is the decision stage making. In the article you have a formula to implement this.

We need to know when a QRS complex starts, so we need to set a threshold for this. The formula in this implementation is:

> threshold = alpha * gamma * peak + (1 - alpha) * threshold

The peak is the local maximum in the window (we usually search the signal with a window of width 250), the threshold is the initial value (the first one can be the firstly found peak), alpha and gamma are randomly created, alpha is greater than 0 and smaller than 1 whereas gamma is 0.15 or 0.20. If the value of the current signal exceeds the threshold, a QRS complex is found.

Here is the source code in Java for low pass, high pass and decision making:

```
// High pass filter
// y1[n] = 1/M * Sum[m=0, M-1] x[n-m]
// y2[n] = x[n - (M+1)/2]
public static float[] highPass(int[] sig0, int nsamp) {
    float[] highPass = new float[nsamp];
    int M = 5; // M is recommended to be 5 or 7 according to the paper
    float constant = (float) 1/M;

    for(int i=0; i<sig0.length; i++) {
        float y1 = 0;
        float y2 = 0;

        int y2_index = i-((M+1)/2);
        if(y2_index < 0) {
            y2_index = nsamp + y2_index;
        }
        y2 = sig0[y2_index];

        float y1_sum = 0;
        for(int j=i; j>i-M; j--) {
            int x_index = i - (i-j);
            if(x_index < 0) {
                x_index = nsamp + x_index;
            }
            y1_sum += sig0[x_index];
        }

        y1 = constant * y1_sum;
        highPass[i] = y2 - y1;

    }        

    return highPass;
}

// Low pass filter; na n-to mesto zapiši kvadrat 30ih števil v oknu
public static float[] lowPass(float[] sig0, int nsamp) {
    float[] lowPass = new float[nsamp];
    for(int i=0; i<sig0.length; i++) {
        float sum = 0;
        if(i+30 < sig0.length) {
            for(int j=i; j<i+30; j++) {
                float current = sig0[j] * sig0[j];
                sum += current;
            }
        }
        else if(i+30 >= sig0.length) {
            int over = i+30 - sig0.length;
            for(int j=i; j<sig0.length; j++) {
                float current = sig0[j] * sig0[j];
                sum += current;
            }
            for(int j=0; j<over; j++) {
                float current = sig0[j] * sig0[j];
                sum += current;
            }
        }

        lowPass[i] = sum;
    }

    return lowPass;

}

public static int[] QRS(float[] lowPass, int nsamp) {
    int[] QRS = new int[nsamp];

    double treshold = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<200; i++) {
        if(lowPass[i] > treshold) {
            treshold = lowPass[i];
        }
    }

    int frame = 250;

    for(int i=0; i<lowPass.length; i+=frame) {
        float max = 0;
        int index = 0;
        if(i + frame > lowPass.length) {
            index = lowPass.length;
        }
        else {
            index = i + frame;
        }
        for(int j=i; j<index; j++) {
            if(lowPass[j] > max) max = lowPass[j];
        }
        boolean added = false;
        for(int j=i; j<index; j++) {
            if(lowPass[j] > treshold && !added) {
                QRS[j] = 1;
                added = true;
            }
            else {
                QRS[j] = 0;
            }                
        }

        double gama = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 0.15 : 0.20;
        double alpha = 0.01 + (Math.random() * ((0.1 - 0.01)));

        treshold = alpha * gama * max + (1 - alpha) * treshold;

    }

    return QRS;
}
```

Comment: @Bo Did you right click on the link and save as? Each entry needs to be its own line?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link below , i think they will help you.

http://www.cinc.org/archives/2008/pdf/0441.pdf

http://carg.site.uottawa.ca/doc/ELG6163GeoffreyGreen.pdf

http://www.eplimited.com/osea13.pdf

http://mirel.xmu.edu.cn/mirel/public/Teaching/QRSdetection.pdf

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecgtoolkit-cs/files/ecgtoolkit-cs/ecgtoolkit-cs-2_2/